# Trouble with renewing a command twice

Tags: lists, enumerate, renewcommand, labelling

I wish to make a list enumerated with colored numbers. The way I found is to renew the \labelenumi command used by the enumerate environment to label items. However, I want to be able to switch back to default and have achieved everything using this piece of code with the help of circledsteps package.

```
\newcommand{\colorlabel}{
    \let\oldlabelenumi\labelenumi
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{
    \Circled[inner color=white,fill color=mycolor,outer color=mycolor]{\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}}
    }
}
\newcommand{\defaultlabel}{
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\oldlabelenumi}
}
```

The problem is that the first time I use \colorlabel and \defaultlabel it works. The second time I switch to colored labels it also works, but going back to default again doesn't (if used inside enumerate group \defaultlabel doesn't do anything and if used outside it results in the code not compiling). I can fix it by manually labeling everything that is not colored and never switching back to default but would like to avoid that solution.

Edit:

Here's a compilable version of the code. If you uncomment the last part the code won't compile.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand{\colorlabel}{
    \let\oldlabelenumi\labelenumi
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{
    \Circled[inner color=white,fill color=mycolor,outer color=mycolor]{\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}}
    }
}
\newcommand{\defaultlabel}{
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\oldlabelenumi}
}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{hardex}{RGB}{204,51,0}
\definecolor{mediumex}{RGB}{204,153,0}
\definecolor{easyex}{RGB}{0,153,51}
\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex}
\newcommand{\ritem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{hardex} \item}
\newcommand{\yitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{mediumex} \item}
\newcommand{\gitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex} \item}

\colorlabel
\begin{enumerate}
    \gitem green
    \yitem yellow
    \ritem red
    \item red again
\end{enumerate}
\defaultlabel

\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}

\colorlabel
\begin{enumerate}
    \gitem green
\end{enumerate}
\defaultlabel

%\begin{enumerate}
%    \item ?
%\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: move `\let\oldlabelenumi\labelenumi` outside the `\newcommand{\colorlabel}`?

Comment: @Tom that actually works. I could have sworn that I already tried doing that, but the original code I had copied had it done this way. Still remains a mystery to me why does it work the first, but not the second time. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom Ok, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `\oldlabelenumi`, otherwise a missing initial `\colorlabel` produces the error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\let\oldlabelenumi\labelenumi
\newcommand{\colorlabel}{%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{%
    \Circled[inner color=white,fill color=mycolor,outer color=mycolor]{\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\defaultlabel}{%
  \let\labelenumi\oldlabelenumi
}

\definecolor{hardex}{RGB}{204,51,0}
\definecolor{mediumex}{RGB}{204,153,0}
\definecolor{easyex}{RGB}{0,153,51}
\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex}

\newcommand{\ritem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{hardex} \item}
\newcommand{\yitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{mediumex} \item}
\newcommand{\gitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex} \item}

\begin{document}

\colorlabel
\begin{enumerate}
    \gitem green
    \yitem yellow
    \ritem red
    \item red again
\end{enumerate}
\defaultlabel

\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}

\colorlabel
\begin{enumerate}
    \gitem green
\end{enumerate}
\defaultlabel

\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I'd prefer a different strategy, that is, define a `colorenumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\newenvironment{colorenumerate}[1][]{%
  \begin{enumerate}[#1]
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{%
    \Circled[inner color=white,fill color=mycolor,outer color=mycolor]{\textsf{\arabic{enumi}}}
  }%
}{\end{enumerate}}

\definecolor{hardex}{RGB}{204,51,0}
\definecolor{mediumex}{RGB}{204,153,0}
\definecolor{easyex}{RGB}{0,153,51}
\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex}

\newcommand{\ritem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{hardex}\item}
\newcommand{\yitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{mediumex}\item}
\newcommand{\gitem}{\colorlet{mycolor}{easyex}\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{colorenumerate}
  \gitem green
  \yitem yellow
  \ritem red
  \item red again
\end{colorenumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{enumerate}

\begin{colorenumerate}
  \gitem green
\end{colorenumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]